# Skip express js view for API routes

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have my API and Website in same Express Js Project and needs to use `ejs` view for the website only. **But not for the API** to return JSON for API routes.

```
const app = express();

// For static website
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"), { 
  extensions : ['html']
}));

// API Routes
const bookRoutes = require("./routes/event.route");
app.use("/v1/books", bookRoutes);

// Website
// Set the view engine for dynamic header, footer on website
const ejs = require('ejs');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

**API**

/v1/books

**Website**

/index.html

How can I skip the view engine for my API routes and apply to `/public` folder only or even for selected files?

Error message, when I open `/v1/books` in Postman

```
{"message":"Failed to lookup view \"C:\\Users\\admin\\github\\test-app\\public\\v1\\books\" in views directory \"C:\\Users\\admin\\github\\test-app\\views\""}
```

The JSON was expected for /books API

```
{
 id : 1,
 name : 'book name'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, routes are matched in the order you declare them.  So, if you put this first:

```
// API Routes
const bookRoutes = require("./routes/event.route");
app.use("/v1/books", bookRoutes);
```

first, then it will get processed before it tries to match any of the static routes.  But, this really shouldn't be an issue because there shouldn't be any files in your public folder that would match a request for `/v1/books/xxx` anyway.

As for the error for `/v1/books`, you will have to show us what the code is for `bookRoutes`.  It appears that error is coming from that router.  `express.static()` does not make errors like that.

> How can I skip the view engine for my API routes and apply to /public folder only or even for selected files?

The `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');` line just configures what view engine will be used if/when some code calls `res.render()`.  There's nothing happening with the view engine on one of your API requests because you should never be calling `res.render()` in an API route.  You are presumably calling `res.json()` instead.

You should ONLY have files in your public folder that you want `express.static()` to match.  That's how you control it.  Don't put something in that folder that shouldn't be served statically.

Comment: @jfiend00 thanks. It's helped to resolve, the problem was not the book routes, but another `indexRoute` which I am using in my `/docs` route to pull the documentation from github API and render on my view which was using `res.render()`